# Has there been any instance in Star Trek of beaming in a tricorder/probe into an unknown environment as a safety check?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

I'm wondering if there has ever been an instance of someone beaming in some sort of probe/tricorder/robot/etc into an environment (e.g. derelict ship, unknown planet, etc) to determine if it is safe to beam in crew? I'm thinking of something analogous to a MALP or a Kino used in the Stargate franchise. I don't recall an instance of this ever happening as they seem to always rely on the ship's sensors.

Note: I'm not talking about launching a probe into space to observe something (which happens a lot).

Comment: "IS THERE AIR??? YOU DON'T KNOW!!!"

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens +1 for channeling Guy Fleegman (Crewman #6).

Comment: I don't know what the range on a tricorder is, but the "ship's sensors" seem to be pretty good at identifying things as precise as a single lifeform on an entire planet, from orbit.  I can't think of any instances of what you describe, and I'm thinking the reason it never happened is because the "ship's sensors" can do the job just fine without sending in a tricorder/robot, barring Plot Reasons.

Comment: In Voyager they once beamed a special device through a wormhole to test if it was safe to beam the crew. But that was to test the effects of the transport beam itself, not the safety of the end-destination. In general I think the sensors take care of this problem.

Comment: Spanning only live-action Trek (series/movies), I don't think they ever use a transported device to perform the equivalent of an SG1 MALP recon. That's what ship's sensors are for. In "The Corbomite Maneuver", Scotty reports conditions aboard Balok's ship by reading something on the transporter console, establishing the ability to perform such remote sensing pretty early in the franchise. Turning the point around, it is the MALP which is SG1's low-tech surrogate for a Trek-style sensor reading.

Comment: Note that Star Trek sensors are good enough that they can beam people back (i.e., determine the exact composition and configuration of a human-sized object at transporter range, down to the subatomic level). Next to that, determining whether or not there's atmosphere in an environment they're beaming into is child's play.

Answer (score 10):

In VOY: "Macrocosm" they send the EMH with his tricorder down to the planet.
In TNG: "Interface" they send a human-sized probe controlled by Geordi to a starship.

A tricorder itself? I don't think so.